# C# Shader error in '': Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' can't really figure out why it is unexpected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

```
Shader "Custom/ColorQuantize" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _ColorLevels ("Color Levels", Range(2, 16)) = 8
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        LOD 100

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float _ColorLevels;

        v2f vert (appdata v) {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = v.uv;
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            col.rgb = floor(col.rgb * _ColorLevels) / _ColorLevels;
            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

I am new to c# and am trying to create some basic shaders in Unity.
I honestly can't seem to find what is the error supposed to be here
ENDCG
}  <--------------
FallBack "Diffuse"

Can't seem to find where the actual mistake might be, unless the whole thing is ridden with errors all together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the "Pass", something like:

```
Shader "Custom/ColorQuantize" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _ColorLevels ("Color Levels", Range(2, 16)) = 8
    }

    SubShader 
    {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        LOD 100

        Pass //<-- THIS
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _ColorLevels;

            v2f vert (appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                col.rgb = floor(col.rgb * _ColorLevels) / _ColorLevels;
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html):

> Each SubShader is composed of a number of passes, and each Pass
> represents an execution of the vertex and fragment code for the same
> object rendered with the material of the shader. Many simple shaders
> use just one pass, but shaders that interact with lighting might need
> more (see Lighting Pipeline for details). Commands inside Pass
> typically setup fixed function state, for example blending modes.